# Logical implementation issue

Tags: c#

I've got five variables:

```
int a, b, c, d, res;
```

I want to find out a value from `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` which is not `0` and assign it to `res`. If all `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` are zeroes, `res` should be `0`. My current code is

```
res = 0;

if (a != 0)
{ 
    res = a;
}
if (b != 0)
{ 
    res = b;
}
if (c != 0)
{ 
    res = c;
}
if (d != 0)
{ 
    res = d;
}
```

Is there any *more consize* way of doing the same?

Comment: What if `a` is not `0` and `d` is not `0`? then `res` will still be `d`.

Comment: To start you could add _else if_ to everything

Comment: Yes, simpler with ternary operator

Comment: The answer go from Else if to array max.. Can we make a concensus on Unclear?

Comment: Really you should explain what is _simpler_ for you. Any question that ask for a simpler, faster, nicer way to do a thing is always a subjective question with answers that are equally valid in a way or another but not for the real meaning of the word in the OP mind.

Comment: Is it possible that the one value not zero is a negative value like -1? Also I wish to know if every variable except one are always set to zero or if they could have other values

Comment: Yes ... only other that 0 or null(which is not possible) i wanted a value to my variable

Answer (score 2):

I suggest organizing `a`..`d` into a *collection* and then *query* the collection with a help of Linq:

```
res = new [] {d, c, b, a}.FirstOrDefault(item => item != 0);
```

Please, notice the *reversed order* since your current code rewrites the previously assigned value

```
if (d != 0)
{ 
    res = d; // <- this will re-assign the res value
}
```

`LastOrDefault` is the alternative:

```
res = new [] {a, b, c, d}.LastOrDefault(item => item != 0);
```

Comment: Ok thanks for advice .

Comment: @Sandeep Pandey: I've edited your question (I've assumed that in all-zeroes case you `res` should be `0`). Please, check my edit and correct it if necessary.

Comment: @Sandeep Pandey: The experience doesn't matter: all *good* questions will be *upvoted*. 
When posting a question, please, do forget that we are **not** you. We can well have *no idea* what `a, b, c, d` are,
what should be assigned to `res` in degenerated cases (say, *all* `a, b, c, d` are zeroes or *none* of `a, b, c, d` is zero).
Avoid unclear goals (i.e. *better* - does it mean *more efficient*, *easier to maintain*, *more readable*, *shorter*??).
Provide examples, e.g. `a = 0, b = 1, c = 2, c = 0 -> res = 2` tells more  (you want the *last* not *first* value) than long description.

Comment: Sure Sir .. thanks ..

Answer (score 1):

Without overcomplicating things, you can chain `else if` on top of the first and so forth. This prevents the unnecessary checks as soon as one of the `if` statements evaluates to *true*.

```
if(a != 0)
{ 
   res = a    
}
else if(b != 0)
{ 
   res = b
}
else if(c != 0)
{ 
   res = c
}
else if(d != 0)
{ 
    res = d
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 5, res = 0;
res = new[] { a, b, c, d }.Where(x => x != 0).Max();
```

Comment: What happened to negative values?

Comment: @InBetween Corrected code

Comment: @InBetween OP needs *any* value which is not zero. `Where` filters zeros out, so we get only non-zero values (which, as I guess, will be the only value out of those four).

Comment: True, sorry, the `Max` is so unnecessary that it misled me. Think about it, you are filtering the whole enumeration and then calling `Max` on a collection of one element, why don’t you just pick the *first element that is not zero* with `FirstOrDefault`?

Comment: All-zeroes case `int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0, res = 0;` will *throw exception* (`Max` from the *empty* set)

Answer (score 0):

What about [ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator):

```
res = a != 0 ? a : b != 0 ? b : c != 0 ? c : d;
```

Comment: or "how to transform readable code into a debugging nightmare for yourself and your colleagues" (though it actually fits what OP' has asked)

Comment: Harder ocde to understand is not what I understand by *simpler*, so no, I don’t thing this answers the question at all. But I agree, not worth a downvote, the code is correct at least, something that most answers here haven’t achieved, amazingly enough.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd like to note that your problem is underspecified, so I'll make some assumptions:

1. What happens if all variables `a`, `b`, `c`, etc. are `0`? I'll assume this scenario as an error.
2. What happens if more the one variable is non-zero? I'll also assume that this scenario is an error.

Ok, now we have a problem we can solve, and we can generalize rather easily. Because this can be reused, we'll implement a method, and we'll use the *try* approach wich makes usage pretty comfortable:

```
public static bool TryAssignValue<T>(out T value,
                                     Func<T, bool> predicate,
                                     params T[] options)
```

Ok, this could now be easily solved with `Enumerable.Single` but `Try` methods don't only want to avoid throwing [vexing exceptions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/) back to the user, they want to *avoid exceptions and their performance implications* altogether, so let's do that:

```
public static bool TryAssignValue<T>(out T value,
                                     Func<T, bool> predicate,
                                     params T[] options)
{
    var found = false;
    value = default(T);

    foreach (var o in options)
    {
        if (predicate(o))
        {
            if (found)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                value = o;
                found = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return found;
}
```

Usage:

```
if (!TryAssignValue(out res, i => i != 0, a, b, c, d))
{
    //failed assignment
}
```